# Are eliptical chainrings effective?

Tags: chainring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the deal with oval chainrings?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/what-is-the-deal-with-oval-chainrings)

I know that eliptical chainrings have been around for a long time and their use seems to have peaked back in the 70's & 80's.  I recently saw a professional rider using them in the TDF and I started thinking...

Is there any empirical data that supports or refutes the claim that eliptical chainrings provide more power output with less muscle fatigue?

Comment: I did some "web-research" on this a couple years ago. After quite a bit of reading, it really boiled down (for me at least) to: "opinions differ". Studies that seemed to be driven by the companies offering the rings claim huge success. Not a lot of independent studies.

Comment: Yep, previous bike came with elliptical rings (and then I ended up replacing one with a Biopace when it wore out), and I didn't really notice much difference when I switched to my "new" bike without them.  If there is a difference it's probably below 5% -- may make a difference on a day-long ride or a pro race, but not going to be noticeable for a 2-hour outing with the guys.

Answer (score 1):

Sheldon brown offers a full breakdown of the biopace rings [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/biopace.html)

[This answer here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/what-is-the-deal-with-oval-chainrings) may be what you need